# IE11 flexbox container does not grow

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

Consider the following snippet:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
.action {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  width: 100%;
}
.button {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 3rem;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="action">
    <button class="button" type="button">
      Button label 1
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="action">
    <button class="button" type="button">
      Button label 2
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

In Chrome, the buttons are displayed vertically and the container grows to fit them:

[image: Chrome]

But, in IE11, the buttons overlap and the container remains smaller than 1 button:

[image: IE11]

Is this a known bug in IE? (if yes, a pointer will be appreciated)

Is there a known workaround?

Comment: Older versions of IE had weird defaults. I always specify the flex-grow, flex-shrink, and flex-basis, because I don’t trust what browsers will think is the default. Try an explicit `flex-grow: 1;` also know that you’ll run into problems with old IE if you use the `flex` option with anything less than 3 values, as IE doesn’t work the same as everything else. You should be able to replace your two `flex-` lines with just `flex: 1 1 100%;` I would also remove the width rule from .action, since it may conflict with flexbox (especially if padding or margin are used).

Comment: Adding flex-grow does not help - tried it on codepen: https://codepen.io/jakubsadura/pen/gdyzJq?editors=1100

Comment: Try putting `flex-wrap: wrap;` on .container. It’s possible that it’s not wrapping and since one box wants to be 100% wide, the other is being forced to 0%.

Comment: just tried - also doesn't help, anyway - thanks for trying to help

Comment: I just realized you have it as flex direction column, so that wouldn’t help. Shoot. I don’t have a computer with IE to help you debug this (which is why I didn’t write an “answer”). I would compare the calculated CSS rules between IE and Chrome. It has to be one of the defaults being different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out! The problem is the `align-items: center;`. I believe this is exactly what you're looking for (no changes to the html):

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
.button {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 3rem;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[image: IE 11]

Side note:
I know the VM box says MSEdge Win10 preview, but this is indeed IE11. The darker blue "e" icon is MS Edge. I had to crack open Notepad and make a local HTML file, since codepen doesn't work with IE 11, and didn't care to fix my indentations.

Comment: I noticed that IE11 displays it as expected when .actions style is dropped. Without

  .action {
    flex: 1 1 100%;
  }

even with align-items: center; the view is fine.
With .action and with removed align-items: center; it's still broken.
I'd love to understand why. Codepen: https://codepen.io/jakubsadura/pen/NLmEMy

Comment: Even in Safari on my Mac, things are weird until the `align-items` rule is removed. The buttons end up horizontally centered, but small. Removing the `align-items` fixes it. What's your purpose with the align-items?

Comment: I don't need it but even if it's removed the view is still broken with .actions style: proof: https://codepen.io/jakubsadura/pen/bxJQQv debug view for IE: https://s.codepen.io/jakubsadura/debug/bxJQQv/xJMjOqVKYXjr

Comment: That's because the flex properties refer to the height, since the direction is a column, and since the `.container` has no height, 100% of 0 is 0. It's a case of, container's height is supposed to be determined by the content's height, but now you're also trying to determine a content's height by the container's height, and so nothing makes sense to the browser. IE says the height is 0 (which actually makes sense to me, and I hate admitting that...) and Chrome stacks them (which actually seems wrong). Give container a height, and action a basis of 50% and watch what happens.